# How efficient is the forward transfer of energy in gravity (surface) waves?

Tags: energy, waves, oceanography

Ocean waves (properly categorized as gravity waves since gravity provides the restoring force within the medium they travel) propagate the major part of the energy derived from winds along the air-water interface. And so they are also called *wind* waves or *surface* waves. But the movement of energy along the surface also leads to movements of the particles of water in elliptical paths that increase in eccentricity, and decrease in amplitude with water depth.

Obviously some of that forward energy in the wave is spent in the movement of these particles - for half the cycle fighting gravity, and the other half being assisted by it. Since water has viscosity the elliptical motions must transfer some (tiny amount) of that energy to heating the local water where this motion occurs.

Is this a correct assessment?, and if so is there way to model it and approximate what the losses are per length of wave travel- relative to forward motion of wave energy such that an efficiency can be estimated?

The oceanographic literature ( I have access to) doesn't address this question, and on-line searches on the subject are buried deep in energy harvesting technologies.

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you are looking for here. Are you looking for a model for the momentum transfer from air to water through wind? Or are you looking for the amount of viscous dissipation done in surface waves? Or something else?

Comment: Indeed water bodies are really prone to oscillation and transmit them with almost no energy loss. I already seen this calculation on theoric energy loss (which is wavelength dependant) at least for deep water, but I don't have an online ref right now, sorry.
Note that with deep water trajectories are circles rather than ellipses. Neighboring particles almost have the same trajectory so there is not much differential velocity for the viscosity to act on. Note that a huge more amount of energy is lost in wave breaking, and on the shore (or friction with shallow bottom).

Comment: @tpg2114 I'm basically trying to estimate how much of the forward wave energy is lost to local water particle (and I suppose yes there would be loss in accelerating the air particles as well!) movements. As Fabrice suggests there is almost no energy loss. I believe that. Waves from a distant sea will travel thousands of miles. What I'm looking for though is with what efficiency. There must be some loss. ).99, 0.999, 0.9999 ?

Comment: @docscience the reason I asked was to see if the energy transfer in Kelvin-Helmholtz instability would help you any. It's somewhat well studied. But since you aren't looking at waves caused by wind specifically, not very helpful. I'll keep looking.

Comment: So I'm on my phone and can't read the article since I can't get on my campus VPN, but is something like this along the right direction?http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v359/n6392/abs/359219a0.html

Comment: @tpg2114 yes, I'm really looking at what is happening after the wind has imparted it's energy